# One specific computer can't connect to internet on one specific WIFI network

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I'm getting the error "Wi-Fi doesn't have a valid IP configuration" when I try to connect to only one specific network. It connects fine to all other networks. I've tried and other devices connect to this network with no problem. I'm running a new install of Windows 10 (upgraded from W7) and my wireless card is a Ralink RT3090 802.11n.

I've tried the following commands:

- ipconfig /release
- ipconfig /renew
- netsh winsock reset
- netsh int ip reset

I've also tried:

- Updating or rolling back wireless driver
- Full Network Reset within Windows
- Restarting the router and computer multiple times
- "Forgetting" and reconnecting to the Network
- Changing settings in the router page (Channel, bandwidth, changing to
  802.11n instead of ax...)
- Assigning a static IP (not convinced I used the right settings which I got from another machine that connects fine, but all different variations had the same result: nothing)

I'm all out of ideas, what else can I try?
TIA! (Please let me know if I need to provide any more info)

**EDIT 1** Sorry for the formatting:

- **I have reset and restarted the router multiple times.**
- **I can connect to the internet through ethernet, but not Wi-Fi**
- **manual IP hasn't worked (although I'm not confident I used the right settings)**

**ipconfig /all for working computer:**

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-UIBVL5H  
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :  
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid  
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home  

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:  

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 64-6E-69-35-F2-CA  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . :   fe80::b6b5:1843:d16e:c32f%13(Preferred)  
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.141(Preferred)  
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 28 September 2023 16:59:09  
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 29 September 2023 17:00:06  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1  
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1  
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 107245161  
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-44-1F-B7-10-7B-44-  B7-9A-30
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 46.6.113.34  
                                       212.230.135.1  
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

**ipconfig /all for problematic computer**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3448]  
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.  
  
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /all  

Windows IP Configuration  

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-P79S0HV  
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :  
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid  
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  



Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:  

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Ralink RT3090 802.11n WiFi Adapter  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : CC-AF-78-56-7A-BD  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3870:dd63:5b4a:d7fa%18(Preferred)  
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.186.214(Preferred)  
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :  
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 315404152  
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2C-A1-96-1C-F0-DE-F1-6E-D6-67  
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1  
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1   
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1  
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

STATIC IP SETTINGS (didn't work):
IP: 192.168.1.150
Subnet prefix length: 24
Gateway: 100.119.0.1
Preferred DNS: 46.6.113.34
Alternate DNS: 212.230.135.1

CURRENT ROUTER SETTINGS:
Channel: Auto
Wireless mode: 802.11b+g
Bandwidth: 20 MHz
WAN addressing type: DHCP
VLAN ID: 20
MTU: 1500
Public IP Address: 100.119.112.39
Mask: 255.255.0.0
Gateway: 100.119.0.1
First IPv4 DNS Server: 46.6.113.34
Second: 212.230.135.1

Comment: What's the network configuration of the faulty device (IP Config /all) and what's the IP configuration on a working device (on the same network)? What type of network is it? Have you tried manually IP configuration?

Comment: When on DHCP is it receiving an IP address on the expected range, one on a different range, or one starting 169.254.x.x which would indicate that it's unable to reach the DHCP server / the DHCP server is unable/unwilling to allocate it an address?

Comment: Reboot the router!

Comment: I've updated with mentioned info. Router reboot didn't work and manual IP either (though I'm not sure about the settings.) Thanks!

Comment: Set the wireless channel to 6 (it may be already, or on auto), restart router, test - if unsuccessful set the wireless more to B/G instead of B/G/N (shortened from 802,11b/g/n which are the backwards compatible wireless modes) -Temporarily turn off 5Ghz too. Some routers let you name the 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz to different names - Either turn off 5Ghz or set a different name (SSID)  let me know the results. 

Also, make sure that this device ISN'T really close or reasonably near the router.

Comment: No luck so far. I've tried all possible variations with the different networks (5Ghz and 2.4 Ghz), I've also tried connecting the guest network and it's the same. I've also tried the wireless mode you mentioned and still no luck. (Sorry for the delay in getting back to you, thanks for the help).

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct WLAN and what do you mean by "resetting" the router?

Comment: Yes it's definitely the right WLAN network, by reset the router I mean basically everything: rebooting, returning to factory settings, unplugging and plugging in... anything I could think of

Comment: If the network really connects to the WLAN put doesn't pass through the DHCP for some reason only for this network is very unlikely, especially if it works with other WLANs. Seems that the fault is either with the main router or you just missed a small step. I think it might be worth checking step by step. Can you please add the configuration data of the routers and the static setup of the end node (device connected to the repeater WLAN)? Also please remove the unnecessary data from your question, no need to see the whole config at this point. (Please add the new info to the question).

Comment: Would you mind clarifying which router settings are needed? I can't any way to export them all to a text file or anything like that.

I think perhaps I didn't know what you were referring to with being connected to the WLAN. The laptop shows up on the router page but only shows its MAC address, nothing else. That's how I know it's connected but without and IP address or anything. I'm also not sure what you mean by repeater WLAN or the "static setup" or the end node (sorry for my ignorance.)
I've removed unnecessary info.

Comment: Please provide any IP-related configuration from the router and the device you set up statically (assuming you actually do connect to your WLAN network, if not more info will be required). If you reset the routers you must have reconfigured them, what configuration did you use?

Comment: I've updated with all the info I can find about what you said.

I say the laptop is connected to the WLAN because it shows up as a device in the router settings page, but it has no IP address, only the MAC address.

Comment: When you try static IP, you should use the same values for default gateway and dns server as the working PC does (i.e., `192.168.1.1`)

Comment: @johnteach TomYan is correct you are not using the right gateway adress

Comment: @johnteach, did you ever find a solution to this?  I am facing a very similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to get the static configuration running is to use the correct gateway which must be the LAN IP address from your router (gateway is another wording for the router in your LAN). This is where your PC will send all packets that don't belong to your LAN:

```
IP: 192.168.1.150
Subnet: 255.255.255.0 (that is 24 bit)
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Preferred DNS: 46.6.113.34
Alternate DNS: 212.230.135.1
```

The IP you have been using `100.119.0.1` is actually the router (gateway) your own router is using to send IP packets to the internet. It is not relevant for any machine in your LAN. You can read up on basic IP protocol and how it works if you find that interesting. There are loads of sources out on the internet with different requirements for preexisting knowledge. Just pick what fits you the best.

The DNS entries are probable both from your ISP, I always put in the secondary one from a different provider, e.g. Goole with `8.8.8.8`

You can use this as a workaround, once you confirm it works we can continue working on the DHCP issue.

Comment: I've tried those static IP settings and it doesn't work (including using 8.8.8.8 for second DNS). There are two things I'd like to clarify:  
(1) I am inputting the static IP info in windows settings>WiFi>manage known networks>edit IP settings. Is this the right place? (2) These are settings for IPv4. I haven't touched the settings for IPv6. Should I? Thanks.

Comment: @johnteach try disabling IP6 for now. Don't worry about the DNS, that's just a side note. Please add the output from ipconfig to your question and include exactly how you tested it (e.g. ping etc.), maybe add a screenshot.

Comment: I think I've already added that info under "ipconfig /all for problematic computer" although I'm not sure what you been by how I tested it. Disabling IPv6 didn't do anything.

Comment: @johnteach you only added the ipconfig output for the DHCP setup, please do it for the static setup as well. Also please try the static setup on a working PC.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your device, it may only work on 2.4 GHz wifi instead of both 2.4 and 5 GHz. For some reason, these devices can see the wifi network but can't connect because they can't handle the right frequency (the device is trying to connect to 5 GHz but it can only handle 2.4 GHz).

I remember a workaround for this, from like 10 years ago when 5 GHz was fairly new.

Let's say your wifi network name is "MYWIFI". New routers broadcast the wifi name on both 2.4 and 5 GHz, so "MYWIFI" is actually two wifi networks using the same name. Here's what I remember doing many years ago:

1. Turn off your router
2. Enable wifi hotspot on your phone (any smart phone)
3. Change your wifi hotspot name to "MYWIFI" (or whatever you normal wifi name is) and make sure it uses the same password as your normal wifi.
4. Make you phone use only 2.4 GHz when broadcasting the wifi hotspot (you may need an app for this)
5. Connect you computer to that 2.4 GHz network
6. Turn off your wifi hotspot
7. Turn on your router
8. Connect you computer to the wifi network (it may even happen automatically)
9. Voilà! (if this was indeed the issue)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just had a look at your wifi adapter, seems like a fairly old computer. This increases the chances of my answer actually solving your problem.

Comment: This explanation sounds unlikely; if a device can't handle 5 GHz, then it wouldn't be receiving beacons for the 5 GHz network either – it wouldn't have any way of knowing that the same network exists on 5 GHz at all, so why would it be *trying* to connect to it?

Comment: My router allows you to have it broadcast two separate networks for each bandwidth, with different names and passwords. I tried that and only the 2.4Ghz one was visible to my laptop but when I connected I had the same problem as before, so I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: Also, the wifi adapter is indeed quite old but has worked on every network I've tried it on except my home network.